# Missing Right Parenthesis error in oracle query ORA00907

Tags: oracle

**Tables Required-**

**PatientMetabolic-**  (functionNo, patientId, score)

**Visit-** (visitNo, visitDate, time, amountPaid, receiptNo, service, medication, chiefComplaints, patientId)

**Patient** (patientId, name, gender, DoB, address, state,postcode, homePhone, businessPhone, maritalStatus, occupation, duration,unit, race, registrationDate , GPNo, NaturopathNo)

**Naturopath** (NaturopathNo, name, contactNo, officeStartTime, officeEndTime, emailAddress)

**The Question is- ** Display the details of patients (i.e. Name, Gender, Address, Postcode, DOB) who haven’t visited the naturopath in the last 6 months and who are suffering from a severe heart problem (the total score > 9 for Heart in metabolic screening questionnaire).

**NOTE** f6,f26,f27 are the functionno which belong to the heart disease. (Score) tells about the severeness of the condition and it should be greater than 9

**My Query-**

```
SELECT patientid,sum(score) from PATIENTMETABOLIC where FUNCTIONNO = any ('F6','F26','F27') AND patientid IN (SELECT DISTINCT PATIENTID from VISIT where TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, visitdate)) > 6 order by patientid) group by patientid having sum(score) > 9;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an `order by` clause in a subquery for an `IN` statement. As a simplified example, this works:

```
select * from dual
where dummy in (select dummy from dual);
```

But this gets `ORA-00907`:

```
select * from dual
where dummy in (select dummy from dual order by dummy);
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/30380).

Even if it was allowed, it would have no practical effect, as Patrick Hofman mentioned.

So in your case, assuming you names etc. are correct, this should work:

```
SELECT patientid,sum(score)
from PATIENTMETABOLIC
where FUNCTIONNO = any ('F6','F26','F27')
AND patientid NOT IN (
  SELECT PATIENTID
  from VISIT
  where TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, visitdate)) > 6
)
group by patientid
having sum(score) > 9;
```

As well as removing the `order by`, I've removed the `distinct` which was just adding a pointless sort operation; and I've changed the `IN` to `NOT IN` because you said you wanted patients who had *not* visited the naturopath. But I may have got that wrong.

Using `= ANY` is unusual, but [valid](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/30381); it seems odd to mix that and the equivalent `IN` in the same statement though. I'd change that to an `IN` personally, not least to avoid confusing people...

Comment: Thank You Alex.. for the answer and explanation.I understood and changed ANY to IN. It works perfectly. and yes u r right about NOT IN also.